# Find the value of $\sum_{r=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}3\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{3r+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, binomial-theorem

> Show that $$\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{4}+\binom{n}{7}+\ldots=\dfrac{1}{3}\left[ 2^{n-2} + 2\cos{\dfrac{(n-2)\pi}{3}}\right]$$

---

**My solution:-**

$$(1+x)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}x+\binom{n}{2}x^2+\binom{n}{3}x^3+\ldots=\sum_{r=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{r}x^r} \\ \therefore x^2(1+x)^n=\binom{n}{0}x^2+\binom{n}{1}x^3+\binom{n}{2}x^4+\binom{n}{3}x^5+\ldots=\sum_{r=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{r}x^{r+2}}$$

In the above Binomial Expansion on substituting $x=1,\omega,\omega^2$, $\omega$ being a complex cube root of unity, we get the following three equations

$$\tag{1}(1)^2(1+1)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{r}}=2^n$$

$$(\omega)^2(1+\omega)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{r}\omega^{r+2}}=(-1)^n(\omega)^{2n+2} \tag{2}$$

$$(\omega)^4(1+\omega^2)^n=(\omega)(1+\omega^2)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{r}\omega^{2r+4}}=(-1)^n(\omega)^{n+1} \tag{3}$$

On adding $(1),(2) \text{ and }(3)$, we get

$$\dfrac{1}{3}\left(2^n+(-1)^n(\omega^{n+1}+\omega^{2n+2})\right)=\sum_{r=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}3\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{3r+1}$$
Now, as $\omega=-e^{i(\pi/3)}$  ($\omega$ being the cube root of unity)

$$\begin{aligned}
\therefore (\omega^{n+1} +\omega^{2n+2})
&= \left(\left(-e^{i(\pi/3)}\right)^{n+1}+\left(-e^{-i(\pi/3)}\right)^{n+1}\right) \\ 
&=(-1)^{n+1}\left(e^{i(\pi(n+1)/3)}+e^{-i(\pi(n+1)/3)}\right) \\
&=(-1)^n\left(2\cos{\left(\dfrac{\pi(n+1)}{3}\right)}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

Now, substituting the value of $(\omega^{n+1}+\omega^{2n+2})$ back into $(4)$, we get

$$2^n+(-1)^n(\omega^{n+1}+\omega^{2n+2})=2^n-2\cos{\left(\dfrac{\pi(n+1)}{3}\right)}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{3r+1}}$$

$$\therefore \sum_{r=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}3\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{3r+1}=\boxed{\dfrac{1}{3}\left(2^n-2\cos{\left(\dfrac{\pi(n+1)}{3}\right)}\right)}$$

> So, where did I go wrong, or is it that the book has provided the wrong answer.

Comment: You've done something horribly wrong: $\sum_{r=1}^{3n+1} \binom{n}{r} = \sum_{r=1}^n \binom{n}{r} = \sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}  - \binom{n}{0} = 2^n -1$ since $\binom{n}{r} = 0$ for $r>n$.

Comment: Oops ,that a major typo let me correct it.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to see if either work by plugging in small values like $n=1,2,3$

Comment: Either $(2)$ or $(3)$ are wrong, since you should be able to take $(2)$ and let $\omega\to\omega^2$ to get $(3)$, which is not the case.

Comment: Both $(2)$ and $(3)$ are wrong since for any odd $n$ and positive $\omega$, the left side is positive, but the right side is negative.

Comment: @Simple Art:How ,can you say that $\omega$ has to be positive isn't it a complex number, representing cube root of unity. As for $\omega\to\omega^2$ in equation $(2)$ to get $(3)$ all seems about fine to me.

Comment: @user350331 No, it could be, but if it were positive, it would obviously be false.  If it can't work for positive numbers, how do you expect it to work for any other number?

Comment: Since $\binom nk=0$ if $k>n$, we have $\sum_{r=0}^n\binom n{3r+1}=\sum_{r=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}3\right\rfloor}\binom n{3r+1}$

Comment: @SimpleArt: But $\omega$ is a complex number, representing cube root of unity, how can you say that it is positive or negative because complex numbers can not be compared

Comment: @user350331 The equations $2,3$ do not depend on what $\omega$ is, $\therefore \omega\in\mathbb R$ is testable

Comment: When you add (1), (2), and (3), you missed a factor of $3$.  But, I don't think the formula given is correct. Plug in $n=1$, it gives non-integer value on the right. So, I think your answer with the factor of $3$ is correct.

Comment: @SimpleArt: I edited the question to set $\omega$ as a complex cube root of unity.

Comment: @user350331 Consider it is, have you plugged it into $2,3$ to see if it actually works?

Comment: @i707107; Shit I made a hell lot of typos in this question let me go and correct that too.

Comment: @i707107: I just forgot the obvious checking by testing the values of $n$, now I think it was waste to post the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha=e^{2\pi i/3}=\frac{-1+i\sqrt3}2$, that is $\alpha^3=1$, then if $k\not\equiv0\pmod3$, $\alpha^k+1+\alpha^{-k}=\frac{\alpha^{3k}-1}{\alpha^k\left(\alpha^k-1\right)}=0$. If $k\equiv0\pmod3$, then $\alpha^k+1+\alpha^{-k}=1+1+1=3$. That is,
$$
\frac{\alpha^{k-1}+1+\alpha^{1-k}}3=\left\{\begin{array}{}
1&\text{if }k\equiv1\pmod3\\
0&\text{if }k\not\equiv1\pmod3
\end{array}\right.
$$
Furthermore,
$$
1+\alpha=\frac{1+i\sqrt3}2=e^{\pi i/3}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}3\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{3k+1}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{\alpha^{k-1}+1+\alpha^{1-k}}{3}\\
&=\frac1{3\alpha}(1+\alpha)^n+\frac13\cdot2^n+\frac\alpha3\left(1+\frac1\alpha\right)^n\\
&=\frac1{3\alpha}e^{\pi in/3}+\frac13\cdot2^n+\frac\alpha3e^{-\pi in/3}\\
&=\frac13e^{\pi i(n-2)/3}+\frac13\cdot2^n+\frac13e^{-\pi i(n-2)/3}\\
&=\frac13\left(2^n+2\cos\left(\pi\frac{n-2}3\right)\right)\\
&=\frac13\left(2^n-2\cos\left(\pi\frac{n+1}3\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$
As far as the periodic part goes, neither is wrong:  $\cos\left(\pi\frac{n-2}3\right)=-\cos\left(\pi\frac{n+1}3\right)$.

However,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}3\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{3k}
+\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}3\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{3k+1}
+\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-2}3\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{3k+2}
=2^n
$$
and since each of the sums above are approximately equal, the non-periodic part of the sum should be $\frac13\cdot2^n$.

Comment: I think the book is still wrong as instead of $2^n$ it has written $2^{n-2}$

Comment: @user350331: Oh, I hadn't noticed that part. Yes, the non-periodic part is $\frac13\cdot2^n$, since this sum is one of three approximately equal sums that sum to $2^n$. I have amended my answer.

Comment: $3k+2$ in the last one.

Comment: @i707107: thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor\pars{n - 1}/3\right\rfloor}
\,\,{n \choose 3k + 1}} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose n - 3k - 1} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{\color{#f00}{-}}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n - 3k}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{\color{#f00}{-}}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{z^{3}}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{\color{#f00}{-}}}\,\,\,
{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n}\pars{1 - z^{3}}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] &\ \stackrel{z\ \mapsto\ 1/z}{=}\
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{\color{#f00}{+}}}\,\,\,
{z\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{3} - 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\sum_{p}{p\,\pars{1 + p}^{n} \over 3p^{2}}
\end{align}
$\ds{p}$ are the roots of $\ds{z^{3} - 1 = 0}$. Namely,
$\ds{p \in \braces{\expo{-2\pi\ic/3},1,\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}}$.

---

Then $\ds{~\pars{\mbox{note that}\ p^{2} = {p^{3} \over p} = {1 \over p}}~}$,
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor\pars{n - 1}/3\right\rfloor}
\,\,{n \choose 3k + 1}} & =
{1 \over 3}\sum_{p}p^{2}\pars{1 + p}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 3}\,2^{n} + {2 \over 3}\,
\Re\bracks{\expo{4\pi\ic/3}\pars{1 + \expo{2\pi\ic/3}}^{n}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 3}\,2^{n} + {2 \over 3}\,
\Re\braces{\expo{\pars{n + 4}\pi\ic/3}\,\,\bracks{2\cos\pars{\pi \over 3}}^{n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\color{#f00}{{1 \over 3}\braces{2^{n} - 2\cos\pars{\bracks{n + 1}\pi \over 3}}}
\end{align}

> Note that $\ds{2\cos\pars{\pi \over 3} = 1}$ and
>   $\ds{\expo{\pars{n + 4}\pi\ic/3} = -\expo{\pars{n + 1}\pi\ic/3}}$.

Comment: Mother of God...what is that. On a serious note, I am a high school student and I did not understand much of what you wrote but just because you provided me with a new approach, so to just understand, can I ask how did this come $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{\color{#f00}{-}}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n - 3k}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}$. And what does the integral denote, is it a line integral.

Comment: @user350331 Sorry. I didn't know you are a high school student. However, it's always useful to see one problem from different points of view. Later, you can come back to this answer to check what you are learning  along your career. Indeed, I prefer the $@robjohn$ answer ( the method ). Anyway, I arrived a little bit later, such that my post has to be a different one.

Comment: I think there's a typo in "$\ds{p}$ are the roots of $\ds{z^{3} - 1 = 0}$. Namely,$\ds{p \in \braces{\expo{-2\pi\ic 3},1,\expo{2\pi\ic 3}}}$". Shouldn't it be "$\ds{p}$ are the roots of $\ds{z^{3} - 1 = 0}$. Namely,$\ds{p \in \braces{\expo{-2\pi\ic/3},1,\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}}$".

Comment: @user350331 Thanks a lot. You're right. Fixed.

Comment: From what I fathom, after looking through one of my siblings mathematics engg. books this looks like an approach through Calculus of complex Functions, which seems a lot more fascinating to me then calculus of real numbers.

Comment: @user350331 You are right. It's fascinating and marvellous.